# Why Do Some Specific Unicode Characters Not Render in Google Chrome?

Tags: html, css, browser, text, unicode

On the same machine using the same font (Arial) I get different text rending from Chrome and IE9:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body style="font-family: Arial;">
IIIIIIIII&#x2AF8;
IIIIIIIII&#x2B46;
IIIIIIIII&#x2A20;
IIIIIIIII&#x27A4;
IIIIIIIII&#x27A7;
IIIIIIIII&#x269E;
IIIIIIIII&#x25B6;
</body>
</html>
```

**It looks like this:**
[image]

**Why does this happen? Is there a way to make Chrome correctly render the two broken arrows which render correctly in IE? (Positions 1 and 3)**

Comment: I've just looked at your html in chrome - looks like 2 and 6 are the broken ones to me!

Comment: Edited: "...correctly render the two broken arrows which render correctly in IE?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your CSS property name has a typo, `font-familiy` instead of `font-family`, so the declaration is ignored. However, the declaration would not affect the rendering much anyway, since Arial does not contain the special characters used. This means that browsers will try to pick up glyphs from different fonts, and their methods may vary here; IE is notorious for failing to do this in many occasions: it often cannot render a character even though some font in the system contains it.

To get better rendering, you need to analyze the support to the different characters in commonly available fonts and write suitable lists as values for the `font-family` property. You may wish to define different lists for different characters, wrapping them inside `span` (or, why not, `font`) elements.

For example, the first special character U+2AF8 (`&#x2AF8;`) is present in a few fonts only, though in addition to those listed at
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2af8/fontsupport.htm
the Cambria Math font contains it, too. So you could use for it

```
font-family: Cambria Math, Symbola, Quivira, STIX, Code2000;
```

You should also set the `line-height` property for the enclosing block element (like `p`) to a reasonable value , like 1.3. Otherwise the very large inherent line height of Cambria Math may cause too large spacing between lines.

Comment: FYI regarding your first line.  The OP fixed that a while ago.

Comment: I verified that this is true. Thanks! Is there a way to make it work anyway? I try to make the meta-description look nice in the Google results. They set the following declaration: font-family: arial,sans-serif;

Comment: Therefore, I am restricted to exactly this font spec.

Comment: @usr, since Google picks up the meta description content as plain text (in the relatively rare situations where it decides to use it), so there is nothing you can do about its rendering. But you may wish to limit the text there to use only characters present in the Arial font if possible. Browsers may well be capable of rendering other characters as well (they are *supposed* to do so, using the `font-family' setting just as a primary suggestion and falling back to other fonts). But in general, very special characters are best avoided in meta descriptions.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Now that I understand the issue I have given up.

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML code is missing a `Doctype` declaration, but even more importantly, it's missing the Character Set declaration.

Read this article for more information:

**[The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)**

**EDIT**:  It's more likely that these particular characters are missing from the OS/browser's various default font sets.  You could declare the proper fonts but if the user's system does not have them installed, this problem will persist.  I tested the code in the answer by Jukka, which I believe to be be correct, and I cannot get it working in Safari Mac because those fonts are not installed in my system.

Comment: That's not the issue here. View this page in Chrome: http://jsbin.com/eyefab/edit#javascript,html

Comment: I added the UTF-8 declaration and verified the file is saved as such. Just to make sure.